# Get Number of element returned by findAllByXpath in leadfoot

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise, intern, leadfoot

How to get the count of the element returned by`this.remote.findAllByXpath()` in intern js (leadfoot).

Comment: Read the length?

Comment: Yes read the length

Comment: I mean read the `.length`.... like the property.

Comment: yes but seems like `.length` dosent work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just played with leadfoot so not an expert but wouldn't it be something like this?

```
foo.findAllByXpath('/html/body/div')
    .then(function (rows) {
        console.log(rows.length);
    });
```

Comment: This is correct. The `findAllBy` methods will resolve to an array of the found items, so just look at the array length to get the number of elements.

Comment: I tried this before but was not working at that time. may be i was missing something.